# What does "tu es si fort" mean?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

The primary meaning is *You are so strong*.

But is it possible to translate it as *You are so loud*, too ?

What are the other ways to say *You are so loud* in French?

Comment: Tu es si fort [dans un domaine]. You are so good! [at doing something].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be confusing since the adjective *fort* can be used in a lot of ways, but not necessarily parallel to the uses of the English "loud".

When talking about people, *fort* can be used to describe the physical capacity of a person:

- *Elle est très forte, elle peut soulever jusqu'à 100 kilos*.
  This is about muscle strength. A synonym of *fort* in this case is *costaud*.

*Fort* can be used to talk about the intellectual abilities or skills of a person in a certain field :

- *Il est très fort en maths*.
  means he's very good at maths.

*Tu es si fort* without further context usually refers to someone's physical capacity, context usually makes it clear, but it can never refer to the volume of their speech.

*Fort* can also be used to qualify a great number of things.

- with smell: *ce fromage sent vraiment très fort*.
- with taste: *ce piment est trop fort, ça me brûle l'estomac*.
- with the volume of speech: *parle plus fort je ne t'entends pas*.

But it cannot be used directly to talk about the loudness of a person. In this case we have to use *fort* to modify the verb corresponding to the noise:  *tu parles trop fort*/*tu cries trop fort*, etc.

Some dictionaries might also give you the adjective *bruyant* to qualify a person who speaks too loud, but *bruyant* usually refers to an overall level of noise and not necessarily to speech volume. The same goes with *tu fais trop bruit* which doesn't necessarily refer to speech volume.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very nice answer in my opinion. So, in French, there is no direct translation for "You are so loud". I think "bruyant" includes all the sounds a person makes, like moving around, slamming doors, playing instruments, hitting objects etc. It is more like "noisy", I suppose. Is that right?

Comment: @Xfce4   Yes, you're right. In the end the choice will be between *Tu parles trop fort* and *tu fais trop de bruit*. And yes *bruyant* (same etymology as *bruit*) is noisy (noise→noisy).  I didn't tackle the case where "loud" is used for the overall  behaviour of the person ("brash")  because I didn't think that's what you meant. In that case nothing around *bruit* will do, *exubérant* would probably be the closest. And if talking about "loud" colours, then *couleurs voyantes*  would do.